# Colour should change of first div 'li' element after drag and drop to another div li

Tags: jquery, css, html, draggable

When I drag and drop elements `li` of first `div` to another `div` i.e "Add your Stories here" box then contents gets dropped. However what I need that the colour of dragged element should change as it has been dropped to `div` 2 i.e `id = dialogIteration`.So that I may  know which elements have been dragged and dropped and which are left to be dragged. Here is my running code to drag and drop.

[http://jsfiddle.net/coolanuj/7683X/25/]

Comment: Please add your code here and point out where you think the problem is. Don't make people go off site to a link that may not be present in the future to look at it.

Comment: You might want to clean up your code, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/7683X/27/

Add resources in the left list. You don't need the html declaration either. Add CSS to the CSS window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the srcElement of the event in your drop function, and then go from there.

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(event.srcElement).css('color', 'green');
    $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
    $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you make your li draggable? via jQuery UI? if so, you can use the event `stop( event, ui )`

it's Triggered when dragging stops.

You can call an eventhandler on stop().

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('stop','#dialogIteration',function(){

// highlight your dragged <li> item
$(this).toggleClass('highlight',true);

});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: @pmandell :Its working for some extent only means when i drag and drop  for more than 1 element its not working sometime .I need to refresh my page again.